# Return a value from a async method call in WP8 C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, return-value

I am developing a mobile app from which I am sending an HTTP POST request containing XML for user authentication purpose to a PHP based web service.

The response from the web service is received in the method `GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)`.

See the some portion of the code given below for sending the request.

```
class XMLHttpRequestHandler
{
    private HttpWebRequest vWebRequestObj;
    private string vXMLString;
    private string vResponse;

    public void SendXMLHttpRequest(string pXMLString)
    {
        vWebRequestObj = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://test.mydomain.com/mywebservice.php");
        vWebRequestObj.Method = "PUT";
        vWebRequestObj.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";


        // initialize the XML string
        vXMLString = pXMLString;

        // Convert the string into a byte array and calculate the length. 
        vWebRequestObj.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vXMLString).Length;

         // start the asynchronous operation
         vWebRequestObj.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), vWebRequestObj);
    }

    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
         // create the WebRequestObject
         HttpWebRequest vWebRequestObj = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

         // End the operation and get the stream for writing the XML.
         Stream postStream = vWebRequestObj.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

         // Convert the string into a byte array. 
         byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vXMLString);

         // Write to the request stream.
         postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
         postStream.Close();

         // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
         vWebRequestObj.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), vWebRequestObj);
     }

     private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
     {
         // create the WebRequestObject
         HttpWebRequest vWebRequestObj = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

         // End the operation
         HttpWebResponse vWebResponseObj = (HttpWebResponse)vWebRequestObj.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

         // get the response stream
         Stream ResponseStream = vWebResponseObj.GetResponseStream();

         // create the stream reader object
         StreamReader ResponseStreamReader = new StreamReader(ResponseStream);

         // read the stream
         vResponse = ResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

         // output the stream
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vResponse);

        // Close the stream object
        ResponseStream.Close();
        ResponseStreamReader.Close();

        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        vWebResponseObj.Close();
    }
}
```

I am calling the method `SendXMLHttpRequest(string pXMLString)` from some other class in my project like this

```
string XMLString = "<testxml><username>abcd</username><password>xyz</password></testxml>";

// send the XML HTTP request
XMLHttpRequestHandler ob = new XMLHttpRequestHandler();
string webserviceresponse = ob.SendXMLHttpRequest(XMLString);
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to figure out how can I receive the response string in the variable `webserviceresponse` in the calling code. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Hope your xmlstring be var XMLString = @"<testxml><username>abcd</username><password>xyz</password>";

Comment: I have corrected the variable `XMLString`...... why you have used @ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class XMLHttpRequestHandler create an Action:

```
class XMLHttpRequestHandler

{
public Action<string> CallbackComplete;
}
```

And in your method GetResponseCallback you invoke that action if it's set.

```
if(CallbackComplete != null){CallbackComplete(vResponse);}
```

In your caller class you set up a method that is called when this happens(you get your response):

```
private void OnObCallbackComplete(string str)
{
//Do stuff
}
```

`ob.CallbackComplete = OnObCallbackComplete`;